# Why is my code taking in self as a parameter within the constructor?

Tags: python, constructor

I'm working on an *init* method in a class called database. It takes in a dict, table and third variable.

Every time I run a file called app.py, I get an error message back that tells me that I'm short of one argument in the *init* method in database.py. This would mean that self is being taken in as a parameter. Why is this happening, and what changes should I make so that this doesn't happen

line in app.py:

```
   dataset = database.__init__(configs['dict'], 'table-name','third-var')
```

code in database.py:

```
def __init__(self, random_dict, table, third_var):
    self.random_dict= random_dict
    self.database= boto3.resource('database',
        aws_access_key_id=self.random_dict['key'],
        aws_secret_access_key=self.random_dict['secret'],
        region_name='us-east-1'
        ).Table(table)
    self.third_var= third_var
```

Comment: `__init__` is not a constructor exactly, it is an initializer, this is, it is called after the instance is contructed. Why would you call `__init__` manually? We need to know which is the class that has that constructor and where are you calling it from.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__` is not the constuctor; it's an *initializer* (hence the name) called *after* the instance has been constructed by `__new__`.

Presumably, `database` is an instance of some class, though it's not clear why it is being called explicitly. When called so, the attribute access `database.__init__` resolves to something like `type(database).__init__`, with `database` itself implicitly passed to the function as the first argument.

`__init__` also does not typically return anything, as in its expected use by your class's `__call__` method, the return value is ignored anyway.

---

Given a simple definition like

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

a call like `obj = SomeClass(3)` is implemented by `type.__call__` (since `SomeClass` is an instance of `type`). Roughly speaking, `type.__call__` is implemented something like

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = cls(*args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        cls.__init__(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    return obj
```

so `obj = SomeClass(3)` is roughly equivalent to

```
obj = SomeClass.__new__(SomeClass, 3)
obj.__init__(3)
```